# Prove that $E$ is dense in the unit cube

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Let $Q_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be the d-dimensional unit cube ($Q_1 = [0,1]^d$)

Suppose that $E \subset Q_1$ and that $m(E) = 1$. Prove that $E$ is dense in $Q_1$.

I know that $m(Q_1) = 1 = m(E)$. And I know that I have to show that every neighborhood around an $x \in Q_1$ contains a point of $E$. However, I am not quite sure how to go about this. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: HINT: Every non-empty open set in $\Bbb R^d$ has positive measure.

Comment: I know this is true, but I'm not sure how to apply it here.

Comment: What is the measure of $Q_1\setminus E$? Can $Q_1\setminus E$ contain a non-empty open set?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. $E$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^d$. So I feel like it could be disjoint from a cube such as $Q_1$. So I'm not so sure $Q_1 / E$ would change anything. I'm not seeing it.

Comment: One of the hypotheses is that $E\subseteq Q_1$.

Comment: So $E$ is contained in $Q_1$. But it's not equal. So I feel like there could be an open set in $Q_1 / E$. I don't see why not

Comment: What do you know about $m(A\cup B)$ when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint measurable sets?

Comment: I know $m(A \cup B) \leq m(A) + m(B)$. That's an inequality I have in my book.

Comment: You should know more than that **when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint**.

Comment: Do you mean $m(A \cup B) = m(A) + m(B) - m(A \cap B)$? I'm sorry these are the only two inequalities in my book about the measure of a union.

Comment: So apply this equation to the case in which $A$ and $B$ are disjoint: in that case what is $m(A\cap B)$, and therefore what is $m(A\cup B)$?

Comment: Ah, if they are disjoint then $m(A \cap B) = 0$. So $m(A \cup B) = m(A) + m(B)$. I will add this to my notes, this seems very useful!

Comment: It is indeed very useful.

Comment: Ok, so what does it do for this problem? Our sets are not disjoint. How can we apply this to help us out?

Comment: You want to show that every non-empty open subset of $Q_1$ meets $E$. Suppose that some open $U\ne\varnothing$ did **not** meet $E$; then $U$ and $E$ would be disjoint…

Comment: Ok. So some non-empty $U \subset Q_1$ where no points in $U$ meet $E$. Then, $U$ and $E$ would be disjoint. Therefore, $m(U \cup E) = m(U) + m(E) = m(U) + 1$. However, since $E \subset Q_1$, it means that $m(E) \leq m(Q_1)$. So, $m(U) + 1 = 1$ meaning $m(U) = 0$. Therefore, this $U$ cannot exists. Is that the idea?

Comment: You also know that $U\cup E\subseteq Q_1$, so $m(U\cup E)\le m(Q_1)=1$.

Comment: Yes that is true as well. So $m(U \cup E) = m(U) + m(E) = m(U) + 1 \leq m(Q_1) = 1$. Thereore, as I had before, $m(U) = 0$ implying it cannot be an open nonempty subset. Therefore, $E$ is dense in $Q$ since every subset must contain a point in $E$.

Comment: That’s right. There is one small technicality that we’ve glossed over: the relatively open subsets of $Q_1$ are not all open in $\Bbb R^d$ (just as $\left[0,\frac12\right)$ is relatively open in $[0,1]$ but not open in $\Bbb R$). However, we can work in $(0,1)^d$, whose open subsets **are** open in $\Bbb R^d$ and which still has measure $1$, instead of in $Q_1$.

Comment: I see. And it is ok for us to restrict ourselves to $(0,1)^d$? Why is it not a big deal to exclude the boundary?

Comment: Because the boundary has measure $0$. You can see this from the fact that $(0,1)^d$ and $[0,1]^d$ have the same measure, since the measure of $[0,1]^d$ must be the measure of $(0,1)^d$ plus the measure of the boundary: $(0,1)^d$ and the boundary are disjoint.

Comment: Ah I see. Is this true in general? In my textbook, we defined $m([a,b]) = b - a$, but they did not define $m((a,b))$. Is it true that the open set is equal to $b - a$ as well? This also seems like a very useful fact if so.

Comment: Yes, $m\big((a,b)\big)=b-a$. You can see this directly from the fact that $\{a,b\}$ is a finite set and therefore has measure $0$, and $(a,b)=[a,b]\setminus\{a,b\}$.

Comment: That is so interesting to me. Not because of the fact (I can see that it is true) but that it is not mentioned in either book I am using. They only talk about $[a,b]$. I feel like this is something that should be mentioned.